# Targeting a Label using jQuery when an extra Span is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label, target

I have a label in a form defined as follows and the jQuery code below locates the 'Description' label and changes it for me to 'Program Description':

```js
$(".ms-accentText").filter(function () {
  return $(this).text() == "Description";
}).text('Program Description');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="ms-accentText">Description</h3>
```

But I have another label of 'Name' that has html markup that is used to tag the label with an asterisk, to define the associated field as being required, as listed below:

The similar jQuery code which is listed below does not locate and change the label:

```js
$(".ms-accentText").filter(function () {
  return $(this).text() == "Name";
}).text('Program Name');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="ms-accentText">Name<span class="ms-formvalidation">&nbsp;*&nbsp;</span></h3>
```

How can I target the 'Name' label, when the extra asterisk related html mark-up code included?

I'm new to using jQuery.

Thanks,

Wayne

Comment: *"I have a label in a form defined as follows:"* That's not a label. A `<label>` is a label.

Comment: Wayne Walker check the answer below and mark one answer who is correct for you.

Comment: Hi adeneo, Karen,

Comment: Hi adeneo, Karen,
Sorry about the delayed response, I posted just before the weekend and wasn't able to test out the code provided until I returned to work after the weekend.
I have now tested the suggestions and can confirm that they both work. I have selected to use Karen's option, as I personally can understand what's happening whereas I'm too green to understand the workings of the Function. But I'm sure that can be very useful when making adjustments to multiple fields.
I really appreciate both responses, as I now have two solutions to my situation.
Much appreciated!
-Wayne

Comment: Scott, Sorry for the confusion. I didn't mean <label> as in tag. I meant a Label used to identify a field in my Form. Hope that clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using combination of `:contains` jquery selector + `append` you can achieve more efficient flow:

```js
$(() => {
  const query = 'Name'
  const $name = $(`.ms-accentText:contains(${query})`)
    .filter(function () {
      const textChildTexts = [...this.childNodes]
        // filtering to select only direct text nodes
        // to skip the asterisk part
        .filter(node => node && node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
        // getting the text out of node
        .map(node => node && node.textContent)
        // joining all the texts into a string to compare
        .join('');
      
      return textChildTexts === query;
    });
    
  const $asterisk = $name.find('.ms-formvalidation');
  $name.text('Program Name').append($asterisk);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="ms-accentText">Name<span class="ms-formvalidation">&nbsp;*&nbsp;</span></h3>
<h3 class="ms-accentText">Project Full Name<span class="ms-formvalidation">&nbsp;*&nbsp;</span></h3>
```

Comment: Much appreciated. This works well for my current situation!

Comment: Hi Karen, I've been requested to add another field to the Form that has the word "Name" included in the field name ("Full Project Name"). The code above finds the presence of the string "Name" within the new field name. Do you know how i would target just the field name of "Name"?

Comment: @WayneWalker I am not sure I understood the question can you rephrase it or show with pseudo code what do you want to achieve?

Comment: The original code you provided worked perfectly. It changed the 'Name' label to 'Project Name', as per my needs.
But the another field labeled 'Project Full Name' was added as follows:
<h3 class="ms-accentText">Project Full Name<span class="ms-formvalidation">&nbsp;*&nbsp;</span></h3>
The code found the "Name" string in that label and changed that field label to 'Project Name' as well.
I need that label to be left untouched as 'Project Full Name'. So is there a way ignore any other field label which includes the text string "Name"?
Hope this helps clarify what I am after.

Comment: @WayneWalker check the code again I updated it with the solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi Karen, Thanks very much for the extra effort to resolve my issue. I've got tomorrow off, but I'll try it out as soon as I get back to the office on Monday morning. I very much appreciate your assistance with this!!!

Comment: Hi Karen, I managed to test out the new code in my work environment yesterday and it worked perfectly at targeting just the value 'Name' in the labeling of my fields. So the other field label that includes the string 'Name' is now ignored, just as I needed it to be. Thanks so much for going through the extra effort to provide me with this solution. Very much appreciated!!! Wayne

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom filtering function that removes any descendant elements and trims the containing text, and use that like this

```js
function f(what) {
  return function(index, elem) {
    var clone = $(elem).clone();
    clone.find('*').remove();
    return clone.text().trim() === what;
  }
}

$(".ms-accentText").filter(f('Description')).css('color', 'blue');
$(".ms-accentText").filter(f('Name')).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="ms-accentText">Description</h3>
<h3 class="ms-accentText">Name<span class="ms-formvalidation">&nbsp;*&nbsp;</span></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll retain it for future use.